# How do I get RadiusNeighborsClassifier to return probability estimates?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The `KNeighborsClassifier` in scikit-learn [allows](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba) you to return the class probabilities of each input.  I want to do the same but with `RadiusNeighborsClassifier`, but there doesn't seem to be that option in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier.html).

I have data with 2 possible classes: 1 and 2

```
rnc = RadiusNeighborsClassifier(radius = 1)
rnc.fit(X, y)
```

I want to do something like `rnc.predict_proba(X)`, so I get an output with each sample's classification and the probability of being that class.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the source of KNeighborClassification predict_proba() to suit your need. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py#L172